# PL/SQL ORA-01031 Insufficient Privilege In conditional statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got pl/sql script which can be run in two modes: 1) on test database where I've got full access 2) on prod database where I've got limited access

part of the script:

```
<code>
IF mode = 'test' then
   DELETE FROM TABLE1;
END IF;
</code>
```

In test database I've got full access to TABLE1 and I haven't got access in prod database so I don't want to execute delete staement. I want run the script on both databses just changing the mode parameter. But the compiler gives ORA-01031 Insufficient Privilege. Are there any methods to overcome the situation?

Comment: @JustinCave - absolutely correct, I am deleting my misleading comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
<code>
IF mode = 'test' then
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM TABLE1';
END IF;
</code>
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing. For example, in the OP's code, the compiler will throw an error if TABLE1 does not exist (even if all the privileges are in place); but it won't if the statement is hidden in a dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: @mathguy If the script gives a compile-time error with the `DELETE` statement directly included then no amount of wrapping it in exception handlers will assist as that would catch run-time exceptions and not compile-time errors. You need to change the script so that it does not generate a compile-time error.

Comment: Right - that means what I suggested won't work either. I will definitely delete my misleading comment to the OP's question.